# How do Data Annotations work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I use Data Annotations in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project to validate the model. These are extremely convenient but currently they are magic to me. I read that data annotations do *not* throw exceptions. How then does MVC know to add validation errors to the model state dictionary? How does the failure to set a property on the model because of model validation bubble up to MVC if no exception is thrown? I always assumed that exceptions were thrown every time a property failed and that MVC model binding caught the exception and added it to the model state dictionary.

To test this I created a console application and added a sample class with a validation annotation to it:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength=3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then instantiated the object and tried to assign values to the Name property that were less than 3. The property assigned just fine, despite the annotation that says string length of less than 3 is not allowed.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObject mine = new MyObject();
        mine.Name = "hi";
        Console.WriteLine(mine.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This little program writes out "hi" to the console. Why? I was expecting it to get angry when trying to set `mine.Name` to "hi".

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You never call anything to validate the properties.  The validation doesn't happen magically on its own.  from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

> Manually Validating Values
>
> When you do not use the DataGrid
>   control to provide the interface for
>   editing data, the validation
>   attributes are not automatically
>   applied. However, you can manually
>   apply the validation test by using the
>   `Validator` class. You can call the
>   `ValidateProperty` method on the set
>   accessor of a property to check the
>   value against the validation
>   attributes for the property. You must
>   also set both`ValidatesOnExceptions`
>   and `NotifyOnValidationError` properties
>   to true when data binding to receive
>   validation exceptions from validation
>   attributes. For an example of manually
>   applying validation, see the Data
>   Binding Example below.

Comment: If I do `mine.Name.` I do not see a method called `ValidateProperty`.

Comment: it isn't on mine.name.  That should probably read "Call the `Validate.ValidateProperty` method from *inside* of the set accessor of a property...`

Answer (score 3):

> C# provides a mechanism for defining declarative tags, called
>   attributes, which you can place on certain entities in your source
>   code to specify additional information. The information that
>   attributes contain can be retrieved at run time through reflection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059(v=vs.71).aspx

Here are three articles to help expand your knowledge of how attributes work. The last being the least important if you understand how to use them. The article is for silverlight but is still applicable to the topic at hand.

[Introduction to Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[DataTypeAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679226.aspx)

[Using Data Annotations w/ silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> How then does MVC know to add
>   validation errors to the model state
>   dictionary?

[ModelValidatorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovider), more specifically, [DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider). This is called by MVC.

Comment: It done in back-end or in front-end? I guess it's automatically create REST API vor validation or something like that, because I can't see anything like that in front end.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not checking if the model is valid... the data notation checks the validity of the model. then you will get your error.

Comment: The only reason I'm not checking if the model is valid is because it's 2017 and I don't even remember this code now XD