# How to set controls visibility dynamically in MVC depending on database records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, custom-attributes

I am looking for setting my controls visible depending on the Database column visibility option set to true or false. I would like to set the controls visibility dynamically. I thinking of using CustomAttributes and setting the ViewModel with it. But I dont know how. A starting point from someone and help me to start.

```
[Visible]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Comment: This might help you get started [How to hide a div element depending on Model value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046108/how-to-hide-a-div-element-depending-on-model-value-mvc)

Comment: I want to use CustomAttribute, This solution is very hardly coupled with the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by **CustomAttribute**?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Well, if you use Data Annotation attribute, you'll also have to write customer Html Helpers. It could be a lot of work for a simple task; it is up to you. [How do Data Annotations work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496705/how-do-data-annotations-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is slightly simpler than ali's answer:

In your Model class:

```
public class Client
{
    [Visible]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Add an extension method VisibleLabelFor

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString VisibleLabelFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var type = expression.Body.NodeType;

        if (type == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
            var p = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

            if (!Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof (VisibleAttribute)))
                return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);

            return html.LabelFor(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.VisibleLabelFor(m => m.FullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple [@helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor) with Razor like this:

In `App_Code\MyHelpers.cshtml` :

```
@helper DisplayIt(object value, bool visibility)
{
    if (!visibility){return;}

    <span>@value</span>
}
```

Then use it like this in your view:

```
@MyHelpers.DisplayIt(@Model.FullName, @Model.Visible)
@MyHelpers.DisplayIt(@Model.Email, @Model.Visible)
@MyHelpers.DisplayIt(@Model.Tel, @Model.Visible)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must perform the following steps:

**Step 1: Create custom attribute**

```
public class VisibilityAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private bool _isVisible;

    public VisibilityAttribute(bool visible = true)
    {
        _isVisible = visible;
    }

    public bool Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Add custom attribute to model**

```
[Visibility(Status = false)]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

**Step 3: Create custom Html Helper**

```
public static class CustomHtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplayFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        ExpressionType type = expression.Body.NodeType;
        if (type == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
            PropertyInfo pi = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

            var attributes = pi.GetCustomAttributes();

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {

                if (attribute is VisibilityAttribute)
                {
                    VisibilityAttribute vi = attribute as VisibilityAttribute;
                    if (vi.Status)
                    {
                        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TResult>(expression, html.ViewData);
                        return MvcHtmlString.Create(metadata.SimpleDisplayText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Use custom Html Helper in view**

```
 @Html.CustomDisplayFor(model => model.FullName)
```